# SwiftUI - LazyVGrid spacing

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a `LazyVGrid` like so in `SearchView.swift` file

```
let layout = [
    GridItem(.flexible()),
    GridItem(.flexible())
]

NavigationView {
     ZStack {
        VStack {
           ....Some other stuff here
           ScrollView (showsIndicators: false) {
                    LazyVGrid(columns: layout) {
                        ForEach(searchViewModel.allUsers, id: \.uid) { user in
                            NavigationLink(destination: ProfileDetailedView(userData: user)) {
                                profileCard(profileURL: user.profileURL, username: user.username, age: user.age, country: user.city)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
           }
      }
}
```

My profileCard.swift looks like:

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Image.image(urlString: profileURL,
                 content:  {
                    $0.image
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        
                 }
        )
        .frame(width: 185, height: 250)
        .overlay(
            LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.clear, .black]), startPoint: .center, endPoint: .bottom)
        )
        .overlay(
            VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                Text("\(username.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)), ")
                    .font(.custom("Roboto-Bold", size:14))
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                + Text("\(age)")
                    .font(.custom("Roboto-Light", size:14))
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                HStack {
                    Text("\(country)")
                        .font(.custom("Roboto-Light", size:14))
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
            }
            .padding(.leading, 15)
            .padding(.bottom, 15)
            ,alignment: .bottomLeading
        )
        .cornerRadius(12)
    }
}
```

This is producing 2 different spaces on different screen sizes:

**iPhone 12:**

[image]

iPhone 12 Pro Max

[image]

Im trying to get the same amount of spacing between the cards (*horizontal and verticle*) and the around the cards on all devices, any help on achieving this?

**UPDATE**

Following the example by @Adrien has gotten me closer to the problem, but when I use an image, the results change completely

```
let columns = Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 20, alignment: .center), count: 2)

ScrollView (showsIndicators: false) {
                LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 20) {
                    ForEach(searchViewModel.allUsers, id: \.uid) { user in
                        NavigationLink(destination: ProfileDetailedView(userData: user)) {
                                    
                                HStack {
                                    Image("placeholder-avatar")
                                         .resizable()
                                              .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                                
                                        }
                                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 240) // HERE 1
                                        .background(Color.black)
                                        .cornerRadius(25)
                                }
                            }
                        }.padding(20)
                    }
```

[image]

Comment: the  problem comes now from the `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)`modifier. Delete it. `Image().resizable()` adapts to its container.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The array of `GridItem` only fixes the behavior of the container of each cell. Here it is flexible, but that does not mean that it will modify its content.

The `View` it contains can have three different behaviors :

1. it adapts to its container:
   like `Rectangle`, `Image().resizable()`, or any View with a `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity))` modifier.
2. it adapts to its content (like `Text`, or `HStack`).
3. it has a fixed size (as is your case with `.frame(width: 185, height: 250)`)

If you want the same spacing (vertical and horizontal) between cells, whatever the device, the content of your `ProfileDetailedView` must adapt to its container :

1. you have to modify your cell so that it adopts behavior **1**.
2. you can use the `spacing` parameters of yours `GridItem` (horizontal spacing) and `LazyVGrid` (vertical).

Example:

```
struct SwiftUIView5: View {
    let columns = Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 20, alignment: .center), count: 2)  // HERE 2
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 20) {  // HERE 2
                ForEach((1...10), id: \.self) { number in
                    HStack {
                        Text(number.description)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 200) // HERE 1
                    .background(Color.black)
                    .cornerRadius(25)
                }
            }
            .padding(20)  // HERE 2
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: The answer is correct, and works, but when i try to apply this to an image, the view is not as your example, any help on this?

Comment: @Gurmukh : You don't need your `HStack`anymore. Delete it with its modifiers (`background`, `frame`, `cornerRadius`).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the spacing is a function of the screen size, in your case. You have hard-coded the size of the card (185x250), so the spacing is as expected, a bit tighter on smaller screens, bit more airy on larger screens.

Note that the **vertical** spacing is consistent and as expected. This seems logical because there is no vertical size constraint.

BTW, the two screenshots are not the same size, otherwise this aspect would be more obvious.

If you want to keep the size of the card fixed, you can perhaps at least keep the horizontal space between them constant, but then you will have larger margins on the sides.

Or you can adjust the size of the card dynamically. Check out `GeometryReader`, which will help you access runtime screen sizes.